# Cloud Resume Challenge - ' Build Failed / Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - pip executable not found in your python environment'

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-sam-cli

I would appreciate any guidance here. I have been stuck on this issue for the last week, trying to find out how to resolve this error.

I am trying to run 'SAM Build' but getting an error saying I don't have the pip executable folder in my python environment. I've been trying to figure this out on Stack, but no luck.

I'm guessing the issue is related to having two different versions of Python installed on my EC2 instance. If anyone can advise here, it would be greatly appreciated.[image]

I've been trying to uninstall/reinstall pip and python. It claims my python version is 2.7, though I have 3.9 installed.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing pip to resolve dependencies.

Try to add pip with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```